# After deploying my rails 3 app on ec2, it doesnt render my app

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, capistrano, passenger

I am using capistrano, nginx and passenger to deploy my rails 3 app from github on ec2.

This is my deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, "my-Blog"

set :repository,  "https://github.com/whatever/my-Blog.git"

set :scm, :git

role :app, "ec2 DNS"

role :web, "eec2 DNS"

role :db,  "ec2 DNS", :primary => true

set :user, 'ec2-user'

set :deploy_to, "/home/ec2-user/apps/Blog"

set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

ssh_options[:keys] = ["#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/my-key.pem"] 

set :keep_releases, 3

namespace :deploy do

  task :start do ; end

  task :stop do ; end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do

  end

 end
```

And when I run the deploy command, everything is fine and my app is on my ec2 under current directory, which means that the capistrano could get my source code from my github.

On my ec2 instance, I have everything set up: ruby, rvm, mysql, rails, nginx, passenger.

But when I go to my ec2 DNS, it doesnt show my app!

Do you have any suggestion what can be wrong? This is my first deploy though!

Thanks for your answer! I expect to see my application! In aws console, I have: 22 (SSH) and 80 (HTTP), which I guess means that port 80 is open. I think there should be something wrong with my nginx configuration file, this is what I have in this file:

user  nginx;

```
server {

          listen 80;
          server_name ec2-54-242-228-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
        #  root /home/ec2-user/apps/Blog/current/public;
         # passenger_enabled on;
        }
```

}

when I comment the root directory, then on the public DNS url it says "Welcome to nginx on the Amazon Linux AMI! You should now put your content in a location of your choice and edit the root configuration directive in the nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf."
and when I uncomment the root directory then gives me 403 error! 
The log file says "current/public/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied)"

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by not showing up. If you're getting a default web page, then your webserver might be trying to resolve a name-based virtual host. In that case, try adding the public IP address of your EC2 instance to your local `hosts` file.

```
123.456.789.012  domain-nginx-expects.com
```

If you are getting no response at all from the server, check the processlist and make sure nginx and passenger are running. Also check your EC2 security group for that instance to make sure that port 80 is open. You can also try telnetting to port 80 while logged into your server:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
```

Comment: That data didn't post. Maybe post a gist?  Also, what happened with the telnet test?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I expect to see my app on the public DNS url!I added more details to my question> Port 80 of my instance is open, I have 80 (HTTP) in my instance security group.

Answer (score 0):

Check the port that is in your nginx config whether it's open on your AWS panel.
Check that you can connect to the port using telnet
Check whether you have nginx, passenger running on the server

```
$ ps -el | grep nginx
```

Check the nginx access and error logs whether you can see your own activity trying to hit the service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added more details to my question. This is my first deploy! when I run: ps -ax | grep nginx
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
 3380 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 3382 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process                   
 3384 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep nginx